# How can I create a log file, one per day, in C# webpages to log info?

Tags: c#, logging, system.io.file

I have successful code that creates and writes to a log file during OnPostAsync.
Every time this page is called it creates a log file with today's date and time and writes to the log file.

I would like to create one log file per day and write to it. I can put time inside the contents instead of creating a new file named after today and time.
I would assume I check for a log file with today's date and if it doesn't exist I write my stuff. If it exists I just append my stuff.

Here is what I am using to create a log file for every post of the page:

```
var newFileName = "logs\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/","_").Replace(":","-").Replace(" ","__") + ".txt";
var webRootPath = _environment.WebRootPath;
var dataPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, newFileName);
```

then at the end of the OnPostAsync I write whatever string of info I need to write.

```
var newCourseAfterSaveInfo = "New Course Saved ::: New Temp ID in Courses_New: blah blah blah ";

 System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(dataPath, new[] {newCourseAfterSaveInfo });
```

I've done this in VB and VBA. The correct file write function will create a file & name if it doesn't exist, otherwise it will just append a line. But I am at a loss to do this with C#.

Comment: I am trying to find a question to answer in this.  Is it that you want to know if it is the preferred method?

Comment: No. I would prefer to just create one log file per day and append to it all day long. 
Currently i am creating a new log file anytime anything happens.
So there are 7 successful OnPostAsync actions that happen in a day. I want only one log file for all those 7. Right now, I end up with 7 log files at the end of the day. thanks

Comment: Use Serilog or log4net, writing your own logger is rarely worth the effort. Rotating logs based on size or date, or both, is a solved problem.

Comment: you are using DateTime.Now.ToString() method which will give you a name that includes time in it as well. DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") will be same for the entire day.

Comment: Also: "Appends lines to a file, and then closes the file. If the specified file does not exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified lines to the file, and then closes the file.." from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalllines?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Jawad! Make your comment an answer and I will except it. Silly me, if it was a snake it would have bit me. AppendAllLines has my needs built in. Thank you everyone else. (I know about logging tools, do not need for this application).

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use in c#

### 1.put the code in config file

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\Work\log\" />
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <countDirection value="-1"/>
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.txt'" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="0" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10000KB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

### 2.show log

```
string logFile = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".txt";
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(logFile))
{
    System.IO.File.Create(logFile);   
}
appendToLogFile(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Serilog or log4net with the appropriate naming convention in the config file.  If you want to pursue your current method, use something like this to specify the same file for the day:

```
var newFileName = "logs\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + ".txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for C#.

import reference

```
using System.IO;
```

Using the Below code.

```
 System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + @"\DataTransferedLogs" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") + ".txt", true);
                        string status1 = "Data Transfered for the Client:-" + clientname + "  at" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                        file.WriteLine(status1);
                        file.Close();
```